# Can't run run script due to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager' Ubuntu Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, firefox, jupyter-notebook

I'm using anaconda, jupyter and have pip and pip3 installed webdriver_manager yet I keep getting this error when I try to run my python3 code. When I run the code in terminal

```
$ pip install webdriver_manager
Collecting webdriver_manager
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/3c/2e2d71aeb28ee73ecaf12b545542b082ca81c8c091bb05028c52c42696ce/webdriver_manager-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests (from webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/1e/0c169c6a5381e241ba7404532c16a21d86ab872c9bed8bdcd4c423954103/requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting configparser (from webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/2a/95ed0501cf5d8709490b1d3a3f9b5cf340da6c433f896bbe9ce08dbe6785/configparser-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting crayons (from webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/0d/e3fad4ca1de8e70e06444e7d777a5984261e1db98758b5be3e8296c03fe9/crayons-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests->webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9f/f0/a391d1463ebb1b233795cabfc0ef38d3db4442339de68f847026199e69d7/urllib3-1.25.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests->webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests->webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/c4/6c4fe722df5343c33226f0b4e0bb042e4dc13483228b4718baf286f86d87/certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5 (from requests->webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/38/928ddce2273eaa564f6f50de919327bf3a00f091b5baba8dfa9460f3a8a8/idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting colorama (from crayons->webdriver_manager)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/dc/45cdef1b4d119eb96316b3117e6d5708a08029992b2fee2c143c7a0a5cc5/colorama-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, chardet, certifi, idna, requests, configparser, colorama, crayons, webdriver-manager
Successfully installed certifi-2020.6.20 chardet-3.0.4 colorama-0.4.3 configparser-4.0.2 crayons-0.4.0 idna-2.10 requests-2.24.0 urllib3-1.25.10 webdriver-manager-2.4.0
```

In my IDE I get this output

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-87a373070a15> in <module>
      9 import requests
     10 from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
---> 11 from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
```

I have been trying several solutions posted on SO but none have fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my case the solution was `python3.8 -m pip install webdriver_manager` and now it works

Comment: so if i have python 3.6.9 then I would just supplement that with the rest of the code you provided?

Comment: i think You should try to type `python3.6 -m pip install webdriver_manager` and it should resolve the problem. I had few times similar sytuation, when i was trying to install package for python3.8 and type `pip install package` then realized that i just installed package for python2.7 :D

Comment: Just tried out your method and didn't seem to do the trick, dang

Comment: Would it help if I uninstall python 2.7?Or even update to later versions of python 3?

Comment: In my honest opinion the better way is start using the newest version, If You don't need to using python2.7 just install python3.8 and everything should working good

Comment: ah ok will give this a go

Comment: @Tomo tried that but didn't work, I can verify that the package is in fact correctly installed on Python3.8 site packages, still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution in case you are using **Visual Studio Code**;

VSCode sometimes is unable to autocomplete some python packages which cause imports to fail even when they run correctly when ran from CLI. This happens very often. The solution is to add such paths to the autocomplete path list on VSCode settings.json.

settings.json is found at:

- **Windows**: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
- **macOS**: $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
- **Linux**: $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json

And add the path to the **webdriver_manager** package to the ***python.autoComplete.extraPaths***, in this case the path to  like this:

```
{
   "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
   "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
   "git.autofetch": true,
   "python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
   "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
       "path/to/webdriver_manager"
    ]
}
```